# how to create an auto complete search textbox in windows 8

Tags: c#, search, windows-8, autocomplete, bing

I found that Windows 8 textbox has a property "IsPredictionEnabled". I understand it is used for enable autocomplete features. But setting this property has no effect even with soft keyboards.

And If i want this search textbox to search bing and retrieve some images corresponding to the search query, how can this be done?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use a cutsom control like this:

[AutoCompleteBoxWinRT](https://nuget.org/packages/AutoCompleteBoxWinRT)

To get search results from bing You need to use bind api:

[Bing API](http://www.bing.com/developers/)

To use AutCompleteBoxWinRT:

**Import namespace:**

```
 xmlns:ab="using:AutoCompleteBox"
```

**Place control:**

```
  <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ab:AutoCompleteBox Name="ABBox" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" WatermarkText="Type something" />

    <Button Content="Test" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,100,0,0" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

Here You can download a sample app: [LINK](http://code.kulman.sk/autocompletebox/src)

Comment: how to use the AutoCompleteBoxWinRT in my project! i have download the package and add its reference, but still i can't use it.